# ¿Cómo validar un update desde un Request de Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7

Actualmente valido directamente en el controlador, ejemplo:

```
    $fields = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:60|min:2|unique:mi_tabla,name,'.$object->id,
    ]);
```

El código anterior es de la función update, por eso en el chequeo se dice el **name** debe ser único en la tabla **mi_tabla** excepto si el nombre pertenece igual (que no se tenga en cuenta a sí mismo).

Mi duda es ¿cómo trasladar esa regla a un **Request** para la validación?

```
public function rules()
{
}
```

Como saben, la validación se debe definir en rules pero aquí no recibe $object ¿hay forma de obtenerlo?

Comment: Tipicamente el id se pasa como parametro de la ruta. Puedes tomarlo de ahí

Answer (score 2):

La manera más sencilla es creando un arreglo estático en tu modelo. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
static $rules = [
    'type' => 'required|string',
    'title' => 'required|string',
    'description' => 'required|string',
    'unit_price' => [
        'required',
        'max:5',
        'regex:/^(([0-9]*)(\.([0-9]+))?)$/',
    ],
    'category_id' => 'required|integer',
    ];
```

de esta manera no te hace falta crear un método. Luego simplemente en el controller cuando llames a Request:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
 
    $product = Product::find($id);

    request()->validate(Product::$rules);

    $product->update($request->all());

    return response([
        'product updated': $product;
    ]);
}
```